# MIP solver on GAE/GO standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, mathematical-optimization

I would like to run MIP solver on GAE/Go standard environment.

I found GO MIP solvers like [Goop](https://github.com/mit-drl/goop) and [Golp](https://github.com/draffensperger/golp). But these solvers requires external library, and can not run on Google App Engine Standard environment.

Is there a MIP solver that can run on GAE/Go standard environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MIP solvers, but I have found [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/get_started) which is in Python and Java which may be useful.

The issue with the ones listed is that they use C libraries which do not work with GAE Standard - However you could convert to [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating) and use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/).